# jquery hide and show method not working properly when given the slow parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i want to achieve is, when i click one of the three tabs, it should fade in a description div on the clicked div, and hide it on the other divs(the description div has the same class)

now, if i use `.show()` and `.hide()` without a parameter(example .hide("slow")), it works perfectly, and if i click the active description div, nothing happens(as expected). while if i use .hide("slow") and .show("slow"), or instead of "slow" i use millisecond parameter(1000), it fades in and fades out just like it should, but if i click on an active description div, it will fade out and fade in back again, which i don't want it to happen. JS fiddle below for reference.

https://jsfiddle.net/k00s1fek/

Comment: It works the same, without parameter it's just instant. So you can't notice anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a simple check to see if the current selector has a div with `display : none`.
Below is the `JavaScript` code needed.

```
$('.col-lg-2').click(function() {

  if ($(this).children('.desc').css("display") == "none") {
    $('.desc').not(this).hide("slow");
    $('.desc', this).show("slow");
  }

})
```

Answer (score 2):

This works fine, hope it helps:

```
$('.col-lg-2').click(function(){
     var current = $(this).find(".desc")
     $(current).show("slow");
     $(".desc").not(current).hide("slow");
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```js
$('.col-lg-2').click(function(){
 
  if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
   $('.col-lg-2').not(this).removeClass('active').find('.desc').hide('slow');
  $(this).addClass('active').find('.desc').show('slow');

  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content=" Një filxhan çaji cool nga Electronic Beats. 
" data-original-title=" Filxhan caji 
" data-trigger="focus" tabindex="0" role="button" data-placement="top">
     <div style="background-color:#d0d0d0;"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/XQeCxxh.png">
     </div><div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(226, 0, 116); color: white; top: 0px; text-align: center; margin: 0px; right: 10px; left: 10px;" class="desc">
a stupid bag
</div>


    </div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="Some content inside the popover" data-original-title="">
     <div style="background-color:#d0d0d0;"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/QJOzklY.png">
     </div><div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(216, 0, 116); color: white; top: 0px; text-align: center; margin: 0px; right: 10px; left: 10px; line-height: 18px; display: none;" class="desc">laka laka lagu iku miku dhe taku ke shpia lakut noren 2 e gjys tdarkes
</div>

    </div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2">
     <div style="background-color:#d0d0d0;"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6gAPzHW.png">
     </div><div class="desc" style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(216, 0, 116); color: white; top: 0px; text-align: center; margin: 0px; right: 10px; left: 10px; display: none;">
a stupid bag
</div></div>
```

Comment: this solution works like a charm too! but i wanted a solution without adding removing classes, but thank you, i saved your  code in my archive.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.col-lg-2').click(function(){
  $('.desc').not($(this).find('.desc')).hide();
  $(this).find('.desc').show("slow");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content=" Një filxhan çaji cool nga Electronic Beats. 
" data-original-title=" Filxhan caji 
" data-trigger="focus" tabindex="0" role="button" data-placement="top">
          <div style="background-color:#d0d0d0;"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/XQeCxxh.png">
          </div><div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(226, 0, 116); color: white; top: 0px; text-align: center; margin: 0px; right: 10px; left: 10px;" class="desc">first tab
        </div>


</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="Some content inside the popover" data-original-title="">
          <div style="background-color:#d0d0d0;"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/QJOzklY.png">
          </div><div style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(216, 0, 116); color: white; top: 0px; text-align: center; margin: 0px; right: 10px; left: 10px; line-height: 18px; display: none;" class="desc">second tab
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-2">
          <div style="background-color:#d0d0d0;"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6gAPzHW.png">
          </div><div class="desc" style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(216, 0, 116); color: white; top: 0px; text-align: center; margin: 0px; right: 10px; left: 10px; display: none;">
third tab
</div>


</div>
</div>
```

**First hide .desc div and then show current div desc**

```
$('.col-lg-2').click(function(){
  $('.desc').not($(this).find('.desc')).hide();
  $(this).find('.desc').show("slow");
})
```

Comment: unfortunatly it doesn't work, but i appreciate the input.

Comment: @masterNixe what doesn't work. Did u checked code snippet. Its working

Comment: yes i did check the snippet, as you can see, if you click on an "active tab", it will fadeout then fadein back. this is what i didn't want.
check the answer and you will see the difference.

Comment: @masterNixe   sorry I didnt read it. I updated snipet ..Check it